# How to resolve upgrading problem in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I have googled about this problem. I've searched askubuntu page about this problem but I couldn't get any suitable solution.

I have faced this problem while trying to update using:
[link](http://lawrit.lawr.ucdavis.edu/it-help-center/how-to/upgrading-ubuntu-via-command-line)
Before that, I've tried to update using update manager too. But, it failed and display suggestion to type code 
`sudo apt-get -f install`

After that, you can see what I got

```
habi@habi-MS-7529:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for habi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up checkbox (0.15.6) ...
[Errno 5] Input/output error
dpkg: error processing checkbox (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of checkbox-qt:
 checkbox-qt depends on checkbox (>= 0.15.6); however:
  Package checkbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing checkbox-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 checkbox
 checkbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
habi@habi-MS-7529:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up checkbox (0.15.6) ...
[Errno 5] Input/output error
dpkg: error processing checkbox (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of checkbox-qt:
 checkbox-qt depends on checkbox (>= 0.15.6); however:
  Package checkbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing checkbox-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                       Errors were encountered while processing:
 checkbox
 checkbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

*Note: It was same error that was seen before typing sudo apt-get -f install

About my computer>>>

Memory      486.7 MiB
Processor      Intel Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00 GHz x 2
 Graphics      Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe(LLVM 3.2, 128 bits)
  OS type      32-bit
     Disk      18.5 GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first fix the dependency problem, before upgrading. `checkbox` and `checkbox-qt` are not that important packages and can be removed:

```
sudo dpkg -r checkbox checkbox-qt
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Now you can upgrade your system.